# Java OpenSource library for versioning files

Tags: java, spring, local-storage, storage, jcr

My task description is something like this:

*"Application should be able to store text/binary files in some filesystem storage. Every file has an author and date of uploading. Application should store all versions of files and provide abilities to review history/versioning tree".*

We can't use DB solution here because we have another application that processes uploaded files and it requires original file version (build script which uses javac command). And this is not good idea to store files in the database.

So I'm looking for some ready-to-use solution and I want to avoid writing my own storage implementation.

I've googled some solutions and see *jackrabbit* library as a variant. It implements JCR specification. But also I saw some bad comments about JCR concept.

Please advise me something else. 
Or is JCR good enough for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That requirement sounds like source code version control. There are APIs for Git and Subversion, and probably for other less used systems. http://svnkit.com for example, a search for "git api" or "subversion api" will turn up others.